# check correlation is meaningful or significant

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value

Let's assume I've calculated the [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) between two variables: How do I check whether this coefficient, or just a number in [-1, 1], is [significant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance)?

In principle, one would calculate the p-value for it but I've read that the [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) isn't that good. Therefore, I read more and stumbled over the fact, that a [confidence interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) is much better.
But how do I calculate it for a (pearson) correlation coefficient?

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation will help you.